# How can a website check if a application is running on my pc

Tags: javascript, jdownloader

Today I've visited a website which allows to download files using the `JDownloader`. There was this image on the website:

[image]

That image changes to this picture if my pc is running the JDownloader client:

[image]

Now my question is: How can this website know, that this application is running on my computer? I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Check the website if it has some java plugin running on browser. I dont have enough knowledge about javascript but, it can not detect what is going on your computer.

Comment: At a guess, it's a browser extension that modifies the pages to include some meta information saying that it exists. Page would use JavaScript to check for that meta info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like JDownloader runs an HTTP server on your local machine and makes the URL http://127.0.0.1:9666/jdcheck.js available, which can then be used to check that it is running.  See here:

http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/glossary/cnl2#check-if-jdownloader-is-running